# Asp.Net Core role system without Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, roles

How can i add role system without identity? I need to member and admin roles.

Login code:

```
  var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginDTO.StrUserID)
        };

        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");

        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
```

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
    {
        opt.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name));
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can i add role system without identity? I need to member and admin roles.

As far as I know, if you used asp.net core cookie authentication , there is no need to build a role system.

We could write the codes in your login logic to check the user role from database.

Then we could add role by adding the ClaimTypes.Role Claim. Then we could use   `[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]` attribute to let only admin role user access.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    //Here build the logic to get the user role from database, then create a new role claim to add the user role.
        var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TestA"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
    };

        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");

        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
          HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
```

On the controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
```